# Android studio: Where should i put my Strings?

Tags: arrays, database, string, performance, android-studio

*Where should i put my Strings?*
I need many relatively long Strings. Only one String is displayed simultaneously called by a switch/case. Should i save the Strings in the Code(in a separated class), in an array, a SQL DB or in the Strings.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am pretty new to android, but from what i understand **res -> values -> strings.xml** is for text or content description set in your layout.xml

if it were me depending on the importance of the data, i would either store it on a class if there is not too much information, or more than likely use sql lite;

Comment: Okay. Thanks for ur fast answer.